# How to compute stochastic integral: $\int_0^t d(B_s^2)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

[image]
Here, $B_t$ is Brownian motion at time $t$

What property is used to compute the integreal
$\int_0^t d(B_s^2)$?

Shouldn't there be some other variable attached with the differential $d$ ?

Comment: Any how, I honestly very much appreciated your help Ian, even if we seemed to be misunderstanding each other. This is why I love MSE. So many great, kind individuals like yourself. I can't believe we have been chatting for more than an hour..!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23069/discussion-on-question-by-piman314-how-to-compute-stochastic-integral-int-0t) ([transcript here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/23069)).

Comment: @DanielFischer May I ask why this rule is in place? What if someone has the same question as me, and wants to see what was discussed?

Comment: One can see what was discussed in the chat if one is interested. (For the formulae, it is advisable to install robjohn's [ChatJax](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) to enable MathJax rendering.) The basic idea is that long comment threads tend to clutter the page, so when a lot of comments are posted in a short time, an automatic flag is raised and we flip a coin or decide otherwise whether to move the comments to chat or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Ito's formula to calculate a stochastic integral, you want to find an Ito process whose differential is the integrand. When calculating $\int_0^t B_s dB_s$, you initially guess (by intuition from regular calculus) that the process might be $\frac{1}{2} B_t^2$. So you use Ito's formula to calculate its differential and get $d \left ( \frac{1}{2} B_t^2 \right )=B_t dB_t + \frac{1}{2} dt$. So you were wrong, but now you know how to fix it, which you can do by moving the $dt$ term to the other side. Then you integrate both sides and get

$$\int_0^t B_s dB_s = \int_0^t d \left ( \frac{1}{2} B_s^2 \right ) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t ds = \frac{1}{2} B_t^2 - \frac{t}{2}.$$